# seg fault during memcpy()

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

#define USER_MEM (10*1024)

typedef struct {
    unsigned short int vol_level;
    int mute_stat;
}audio_state;

static audio_state aud_stat;

static unsigned char user_mem[USER_MEM];

void aud_read(unsigned char * data)
{
    unsigned short pos =0;
    memcpy(data,&user_mem[pos],sizeof(data));
    printf("The Read data is:%c",*data);
}

void aud_write(unsigned char * data)
{
    unsigned short pos =0;
    memcpy(&user_mem[pos],data,sizeof(user_mem[pos]));
    printf("The written data is:%s",*data);
}

int main()
{  
    aud_stat.vol_level=10;
    aud_stat.mute_stat=20;

    aud_write((unsigned char*)&aud_stat);
    aud_read((unsigned char*)&aud_stat);
}
```

This program is throwing a segmentation fault. I wanted to read some bytes of data as well as to write some bytes of data. I have written the above code but it's throwing an error as seg fault. Please help me to resolve this issue.

**EDITED**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

#define USER_MEM (10*1024)

typedef struct {
    unsigned short int vol_level;
    int mute_stat;
}audio_state;

static audio_state aud_stat;

static unsigned char user_mem[USER_MEM];

void read(unsigned char * data,unsigned short num)
{
    printf("Into Read!\n");
    unsigned short pos =0;
    memcpy(data,&user_mem[pos],num);
    printf("The Read data is:%c",*data);
}

void write(unsigned char * data,unsigned short num)
{
    printf("Into Write!\n");
    unsigned short pos =0;
    memcpy(&user_mem[pos],data,num);
    printf("The written data is:%c",*data);
}

int main()
{
    aud_stat.vol_level=10;
    aud_stat.mute_stat=20;
    write((unsigned char*)&aud_stat,sizeof(audio_state));
    read((unsigned char*)&aud_stat,sizeof(audio_state));
}
```

output:

Comment: Did you run it through a debugger? Did you check that the pointers given to `memcpy` was valid?

Comment: I'm using codepad.I dont have C softwares installed in .

Comment: @Angus: I suggest you get one.

Comment: Why was this question downvoted? It seems to be a fair question and it underlines the importance of a debugger when working with pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, your use of `read()` and `write()` shadows the system-supplied `read(2)` and `write(2)` routines. This is a giant mistake. (You *can* replace the system-supplied system call wrappers but you had better make sure you do as good a job programming them as the system C library authors did in the first place. Yours aren't even *close* to what the system-supplied `read(2)` and `write(2)` functions do.) Your `printf(3)` call will try to use `write(2)` internally to write your output and will find your implementation instead. Because yours handles its parameters very differently than the `write(2)` implementation, it'll probably die on that `memcpy()` call -- you've dereferenced the first argument to `write()` as if it were a pointer, but `printf(3)` will call it with an integer like `1`. Dereferencing `1` is a sure-fire way to segfault.

Second, you cannot use `sizeof` on an array passed into a function as a parameter. Arrays passed as parameters decay to pointers -- your function cannot determine if it was called with an array or a character pointer, and `sizeof` is going to calculate (at compile time!) the size of a *pointer*. Huge difference. Either pass array sizes in the parameters or use compile-time `#defines` to make them the same across the whole project.

Third:

> ```
> void write(unsigned char * data)
> /* .... */
> printf("The written data is:%s",*data);
> ```

This has the effect of passing a *single character* to `printf(3)` but your format string suggested you were going to pass a "string". C strings are `NUL`-terminated `char` arrays -- who knows when the next `'\0'` byte in the input you've given it is going to come.

Fourth:

> ```
> void write(unsigned char * data)
> /* ... */
> aud_stat.mute_stat=20;
> write((unsigned char*)&aud_stat);
> ```

You're making dangerous (and needless) casts away from your structure type to a completely unrelated type. Your new `write()` replacement should look something more like `void write_aud(audio_state *a)`, so you can work with your objects directly.

I strongly recommend reading [The C Programming Language by Kernighan and Ritchie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language) before spending much more time on this program -- trying to debug this one into existence is going be a painfully slow way to learn C.

Answer (score 1):

In `AIUP_read` you can not use `sizeof(data)`! The size returned will be that of the *pointer*, not what it points to. You must supply the length of data to the functions `AIUP_read` and `AIUP_write`.

Comment: I am doing strlen(data) and strlen(user_mem[pos]). Is this correct.Pls help

Answer (score 1):

Your crash is in `AIUP_write`:

```
printf("The written data is:%s",*data);
```

you are attempting to read a string, thus crashing (change to '%d' to print the value of `vol_level`).

There are other logic issues, related to the use of sizeof and the use of `pos`, which is always 0.

A debugger shows these problems quite easily:

```
(gdb) r
Starting program: /private/tmp/a.out 
Reading symbols for shared libraries +........................ done

Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
Reason: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at address: 0x0000000000000000
0x00007fff8e22e4f0 in strlen ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007fff8e22e4f0 in strlen ()
#1  0x00007fff8e1cf8c3 in __vfprintf ()
#2  0x00007fff8e1ce18e in vfprintf_l ()
#3  0x00007fff8e1d72d0 in printf ()
#4  0x0000000100000e12 in write (data=0x100003880 "\n") at test2.c:26
#5  0x0000000100000e4e in main () at test2.c:33
(gdb) list 26,26
26  printf("The written data is:%s",*data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, there's a couple of problems here. First, your use of `sizeof` seems to be wrong. In each case it looks like you're trying to read/write and `audio_state` structure, so you should be using `sizeof(audio_state)` to copy the entire structure. `sizeof(data)` will probably give you 4 on a 32bit machine and 8 on a 64bit machine, while `sizeof(user_mem[pos])` is going to be 1.

Secondly, your `printf` statements are using `%c` in one case and `%s` in another. I suspect the reason for the seg-fault is the line:

`printf("The written data is:%s",*data);`

You're telling `printf` to expect a string (a `char*`) but you're passing in `*data` which is an `unsigned char`. `printf` will cast this char to a `char*` and try to access the address. Since it's not a string it's going to fault.

Comment: Sean : you are right!. I got no errors . But the output could not be printed out.Please see the edit

Comment: Please help me to identify where the mistake is!.